# traefik - Route Path to root context host.com/mailcatcher - > container/

Tags: reverse-proxy, docker-swarm, traefik

I'm trying to host mailcatcher in docker swarm and serve it with Traefik. I'm running mailcatcher as a service which unfortunately hosts itself on the / root context path like localhost:10980/. I have a frontend rule /mailcatcher with PathPrefixStrip so the initial load works but then the app tries to reach host.com/assets which obviously doesn't exists. Does traefik has any solution like the sub_filter option in nginx to route these requests or do I have to add these as a frontend rule to be able to host it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you check the entrypoints documentation? https://docs.traefik.io/toml/#entrypoints-definition Would the URL rewrite work for you?

Comment: Yes I checked it but URL rewrite mean really rewrite the URL so host.com/mailcatcher would become host.com/ which again not good since that's not hosted in traefik. In nginx it's possible with sub_filter which will rewrite substring in the response so when mailcatcher sends a request with /assets it'll really go to /mailcatcher/assets which will exists in traefik.

In nginx we solved it with the following proxy conf:
`location ~ ^/mailcatcher/(.*)$ {
    proxy_pass http://mailcatcher-upstream/$1$is_args$args;
    sub_filter '/assets/' '/mailcatcher/assets/';
}`

Comment: I am also having the same kind of requirement with docker container. With default installation web part is accessible at `http://localhost:80/`. Instead of this I want it to be accessible at `http://localhost:80/mailcatcher`.

Comment: @jgrasl Could you expalin in detail how did you implement this?

Comment: @KrishnaKuntala First we used some nginx sub_filter rule but now mailcatcher has an http-path setting so you can start it with /mailcatcher instead of /. Only the attachment doesn't seem to work with it hopefully it'll get fixed. You can find more info about it here: https://github.com/sj26/mailcatcher/issues/227